# iOS background wake on password protected device

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-location, region-monitoring

In Apple Doc [Understanding When Your App Gets Launched into the Background](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html) says

> When password protection is enabled on the device, the system does not
>   launch an app in the background before the user first unlocks the
>   device.

Users cannot keep unlocking there iPhones after every few minute that some app will wake in background.

How an region monitoring app will wake in background and do its stuff when an password protected device will not let the app launch in background?

What is the meaning of that is written in Apple doc?

Comment: Could you state your question as a _question_? As it stands right now, it is not immediately clear _what_ your problem is.

Comment: @NicolasMiari please check my edited question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you misunderstood the documentation.

> In most cases, the system does not relaunch apps **after they are
>   force quit** by the user. One exception is location apps, which in iOS
>   8 and later are relaunched after being force quit by the user. In
>   other cases, though, the user must launch the app explicitly or reboot
>   the device before the app can be launched automatically into the
>   background by the system. When password protection is enabled on the
>   device, the system does not launch an app in the background before the
>   user first unlocks the device

So what it means is that **if** the user **force quit** your app on a password protected iPhone:

1. If this is a location service
   => User must **unlock** the phone before a background operation can be executed
2. If this is not a location service 
   => User must **unlock** AND **launch the app once** before background operation can be executed.

In any case, once the app has been **launched once**, background operation **can** be triggered.

Comment: if I set region monitoring in my app and then quit the app and lock my iPhone which is password protected then still app will be waked in background. But If I restart my iPhone then once I have to launch app so it can wake in background?

Comment: In your case since this is a location service, if you reboot the password protected iPhone, you'll only have to unlock it once before the background operation can run